# Android Accessibility : Feedback to password not provided when head phones are connected

Tags: android, accessibility

I am trying to provide accessibility to my application. I am facing one problem with speaking of passwords. According to https://support.google.com/accessibility/android/answer/6006977?hl=en feedback to password is provided when a user connects his head phone irrespective of speak password checked/ unchecked in settings-> accessibility.

In my application it is saying "dot" instead of reading the letters typed. Is there any programmatic setting that has to be followed to achieve this feature.